# How to create a function that ignores the first parameter when it's not present?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm creating a custom `console.log`:

```
util.log = (text, value) => {
  console.log(text, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)))
}
```

It works fine if I do this: `util.log('result:', result)`, but if I do this `util.log(result)`, nothing is logged.

How to modify the function so it omits `text` and logs `value` when `text` is not present?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)) === value` http://developers.squarespace.com/what-is-json/

Comment: @tmslnz not true, JSON.stringify will omit some values (mainly functions and things on the prototype)

Comment: @tmslnz—not if *value* is any kind of object, such as a plain object, array, function, date, etc.

Comment: Thank you @nem035 and Rob, didn't know this trick/workaround. Is it not slow (computer-slow, I mean)?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using an arrow function, which has no access to the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object, you can use the [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) operator to accumulate the arguments passed in and then based on their length, do the appropriate print:

```
util.log = (...args) => {
  if (args.length === 2) {
    const [text, value] = args;
    console.log(text, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)));
  } else {
    const [value] = args;
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)));
  }
}
```

Another good option, as [suggested by Harry Robbins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40518669/3928341), is to reverse the order of arguments in your function by putting the required argument first and the optional second which could make the usage cleaner and more logical.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

```
util.log = (text, value) => {
  if (value === undefined) {
    value = text;
    text = "%s";
  }
  console.log(text, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)))
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this log `undefined, {obj}`, when only the object is passed in?

Comment: Yes. The `test` parameter is treated as optional, and if you log it when it is "missing", it will be undefined.

Comment: But the OP wants to omit the log of `text`, when its not present, not log `undefined`? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can add some logic to the beginning of your function that will set value to equal the text argument if value is undefined and text is the proper type. Checking the proper type is an additional safeguard, but not absolutely necessary.
Then do the same check and set the text variable equal to a default string or the first argument.

You can check arguments.length to see if its greater than 1, or check for whether a specific argument is undefined.

```
util.log = (text, value) => {
    value = (typeof value === "undefined" && typeof text === "object") ? text : value;
    text = (typeof value === "undefined") ? "Value: " + : text;
    console.log(text, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)))
}
```

The cleaner way to do this imo is to make required arguments first in order, and optional arguments at the end.

i.e.

```
util.log = (value, text) => {
  text = text || "Value: ";
  console.log(text, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Function.prototype.apply()`,  `Array.prototype.filter()` to pass only defined parameter to `console.log()`

```js
util = {log : ({text, value}) => 
        console.log.apply(null
        , [text, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))].filter(Boolean));
};

util.log({value:[1,2,3]});

util.log({text:"result:", value:[1,2,3]});
```